# .NET XmlSerializer and multidimensional arrays

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, xmlserializer

I'm implementing a program which acts as a client to some existing software. The protocol is defined using an `XML` schema, and it includes multidimensional arrays.

The .net `XmlSerializer` cannot handle those - *it's a known issue*.

Is there a way to extend `XmlSerializer` so I can implement handling for this, or is there a full (free or commercial) replacement for `XmlSerializer` that can handle multidimensional arrays?

[`SharpSerializer`](https://sharpserializer.codeplex.com/) does not seem to create schema defined XML, but uses it's own serialization format.

I guess I can use `sgen.exe` to generate the serializer code, and then edit that manually afterwards to add the necessary handling, but I would like to avoid that.

Comment: You could add a property to your class which gives you a string of your array field. Ignore the array field with XmlIgnore and make the property serializable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control to change your schema, you could try use **jagged arrays** instead of multidimensional arrays.

`string[][]` instead of `string[,]`

or use something like `List<List<T>>`

You can create your own **custom class** which *flattens* the multidimensional array.

Alternatively, use XmlIgnore on your class, *flatten* the multidimensional array into a standard array (as proposed [here by Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553824/serializing-an-array-of-integers-using-xmlserializer))

```
[XmlIgnore]
public int[, ,] Data { get; set; }

[XmlElement("Data"), Browsable(false)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public int[] DataDto
{
    get { /* flatten from Data */ }
    set { /* expand into Data */ }
}
```

Comment: What sort of thing goes in those get and set braces?

Comment: I've answered my own comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553824/serializing-an-array-of-integers-using-xmlserializer/43050791#43050791